# Line 31:9: Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 8 react/jsx-indent

Tags: reactjs, jsx, lint

When I run my app normally using `npm start` it works fine. But when I try creating a build directory with a production build of my app using `npm run build`.I get a warning that I should have spaces, where indentation seems normally set up:

Error

```
[eslint] 
src/App.js
  Line 9:2:    Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 1    react/jsx-indent
  Line 10:2:   Expected indentation of 3 space characters but found 1    react/jsx-indent
  Line 11:9:   Expected indentation of 3 space characters but found 8    react/jsx-indent
  Line 12:9:   Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 8   react/jsx-indent
  Line 14:9:   Expected indentation of 3 space characters but found 8    react/jsx-indent
  Line 15:9:   Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 8   react/jsx-indent
  Line 25:9:   Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 8   react/jsx-indent
  Line 27:11:  Expected indentation of 12 space characters but found 10  react/jsx-indent
  Line 29:25:  Expected indentation of 12 space characters but found 10  react/jsx-indent
  Line 31:9:   Expected indentation of 10 space characters but found 8   react/jsx-indent
  Line 31:9:   Expected closing tag to match indentation of opening      react/jsx-closing-tag-location
```

eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  rules: {
    indent: 'off',
    "react/jsx-indent": [2, 2] ,
    'template-curly-spacing': 'off',
    'import/extensions': 0,
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'linebreak-style': 0,
    'react/state-in-constructor': 0,
    'import/prefer-default-export': 0,
    'max-len': [
      2,
      250,
    ],
    'no-multiple-empty-lines': [
      'error',
      {
        max: 1,
        maxEOF: 1,
      },
    ],
    'no-underscore-dangle': [
      'error',
      {
        allow: [
          '_d',
          '_dh',
          '_h',
          '_id',
          '_m',
          '_n',
          '_t',
          '_text',
        ],
      },
    ],
    'object-curly-newline': 0,
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': 0,
    'react/jsx-one-expression-per-line': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/alt-text': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-autofocus': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions': 0,
    'react/no-array-index-key': 0,
    'jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid': [
      'error',
      {
        components: [
          'Link',
        ],
        specialLink: [
          'to',
          'hrefLeft',
          'hrefRight',
        ],
        aspects: [
          'noHref',
          'invalidHref',
          'preferButton',
        ],
        "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}]
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

What I have tried.

- using "react/jsx-indent" config option
- `npm run lint -- --fix`
- disabling lint
- Changing indentation settings in VScode

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it by using Prettier to format the code in the `app.js` file. Since I had prettier installed I just used `CTRL + SHIFT + P` Then searched `format document`